# Estimate of sums over primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $p$ be prime and $f$ a real arithmetic function.

1. If $$\sum_{p\leq x} \frac{f(p)}{\sqrt p}=o\left(\frac{x}{\log x}\right),  $$
   How to estimate $$ \sum_{p\leq x} f(p)?  $$
2. If $$\sum_{p\leq x} f(p)^2=O\left(\frac{x}{\log x}\right),  $$
   How to estimate $$ \sum_{p\leq x} \frac{f(p)^2}{p}?  $$
   I feel we need to use the Abel summation formula, but the index here is $p$, is there a prime version of Abel summation?

Comment: you're right (and for the first sum you don't even need that).  and don't forget the coefficients $a_n$ in abel summation are just general coefficients $a_n$.  (can be prime, can be whatever)

Comment: As tomos said. Let $a(n):=f(n)$ for $n$ prime, and $a(n):=0$ for $n$ composite. Now do the usual things with Abel summation.